# update mysql database where current value is greater then old value codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

we have a table "products" with two columns name code and price , i update this table with where code = "something" condition ,

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET price='20' WHERE code=2";
```

and easily update price . but  we want our query check , if our uploaded data is lower than old data , then our value will not update , and if our uploaded data is greater than old value of price , then price updated ., means we want always price value is maximum ??what is way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the condition in the filter:

```sql
UPDATE products SET price = 20 WHERE code = 2 AND price < 20
```

Or else, you can use MySQL's [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function:

```sql
UPDATE products SET price = GREATEST(price, 20) WHERE code = 2
```

Comment: but i want compare value , which is already in database price column , means how we compare our current value (which we want upload) and old value(which is now in database)

Comment: @diossul: Yes.  Both of the above do exactly that.  What's the problem?

Comment: but what query we use compare both values

Comment: @diossul: Either of the above.

Comment: no no sir here you compare price with 20 , but we want compare our current value and old uploaded value in table for price

Comment: where do you take *our current value* ?